# gSoap reponse is not having xsi:type giving

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><env:Header/>
<env:Body><m:authenticateResponse xmlns:m="http://www.wsso.xxxx.com/XYZAuth">
<result>0:</result></m:authenticateResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

when parsing this response from web service i am getting

> Push namespace binding (level=2)
>   'm'='http://www.wsso.xxxx.com/XYZAuth' Push OK ('m' matches 'ldap' in
>   namespace table) Begin tag found (level=3) 'm:authenticateResponse'=''
>   Enter id='' type=638 location=(nil) size=4
>   stdsoap2_ssl.c(10118): malloc(16) = 0x9e13060 lookup type id='' NOT
>   FOUND! Need to get it from xsi:type

going in infinte loop

Comment: Error is : lookup type id='' NOT FOUND! Need to get it from xsi:type

Comment: Please, reformat/rephrase your question, it is hard to read, easy misinterpret.

Comment: The log reports that an 'id' attribute was found but I don't see it in the log message. I also don't see the ldap namespace in the message snippet. It is not clear what your question is.